# Wiremock - redirect to proxy when first mapping error

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, stub, wiremock

I'm trying to use Wiremock 2.24.1 to dynamically return different bodies files, depending on request path, and if not found locally I would like to call an external resource (as a proxy).

I'm using this mapping file:

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request" : {
    "urlPattern" : "/rest/v2/name/.*",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "bodyFileName" : "rest_v2_name_{{request.requestLine.pathSegments.[3]}}_body.json",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    },
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}
```

And I have one file named **rest_v2_name_springfield_body.json** with this content

```
[
    {
        "name": "Springfield",
        "now": "{{now}}",
        "yesterday"; "{{now offset='-1 days' format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ'}},
        "tomorrow"; "{{now offset='1 days' format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ'}}
    }
]
```

returned when I call *curl [http://localhost:8099/rest/v2/name/springfield](http://localhost:8099/rest/v2/name/springfield_)* :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Springfield",
        "now": "2019-08-17T00:23:12Z",
        "yesterday"; "2019-08-15 21:23:12-0300,
        "tomorrow"; "2019-08-17 21:23:12-0300
    }
]
```

If I call with another path value (like **http://localhost:8099/rest/v2/name/brasil**) I want to be handled by this other mapping:

```
{
  "priority": 10,
  "request" : {
    "urlPattern" : "/rest/v2/name/.*",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response" : {
    "proxyBaseUrl" : "http://restcountries.eu"
  }
}
```

But instead of answering the response of **http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/brasil**, I'm getting a local HTTP 500 Error with this message (I believe it's from the first matching mapping):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./__files/rest_v2_name_brasil_body.json
```

I tried this alternatives

- I disabled the first mapping (just for sure), and wiremock worked as a proxy as expected.
- I tried a broader urlPattern ".*" on proxy mapping file, but didn't worked, first mapping still answered the call.
- I switched the priorities (1 to proxy and 10 to local mapping), but all the calls where answered by the proxy, including the "springfield".

Is there a way to solve this scenario without coding ?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the proxy `on/off`, Wiremock will always follow the priorities.

> Considering that you have the same request pattern,
>
> Case-I : When you have `Proxy(brasil) at priority 1` and `stub-mapping(spingfield) at priority 10` : You will be getting all the responses through Proxy only. There is no failover check for other mappings kind of thing.
>
> Case-I : When you have `Proxy(brasil) at priority 10` and `stub-mapping(spingfield) at priority 1` : You will be getting the same response as stub-mapping you have configured since every request will be going to satisfy the `springfield` rule.

To solve this, you need to record every request when you are on Proxy.

Once you stop the recording, you can check for the mappings and add additional mappings as per you requirement !